# How to predict in multiple models consisting of tensorflow (.pb) model and keras model (.h5) at the same time in flask?

Tags: tensorflow, flask, keras

I try to describe the situations completely. But due to my ability of language, there will be possible some unclear statements. Please let me know. I will try to explain my meaning.

Recently, I want to apply facenet (I mean davisking's project on github) to my project. Therefore, I wrote a class

```
class FacenetEmbedding:
def __init__(self, model_path):
    self.sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
    self.sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    # Load the model
    facenet.load_model(model_path)
    # Get input and output tensors
    self.images_placeholder = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("input:0")
    self.tf_embeddings = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("embeddings:0")
    self.phase_train_placeholder = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("phase_train:0")

def get_embedding(self, images):
    feed_dict = {self.images_placeholder: images, self.phase_train_placeholder: False}
    embedding = self.sess.run(self.tf_embeddings, feed_dict=feed_dict)
    return embedding

def free(self):
    self.sess.close()
```

I can use this class independent in flask.

```
model_path = "models/20191025-223514/"
fe = FacenetEmbedding(model_path)
```

But I have different demands later. I train two models by using keras. I want to use them (.h5 model) with the above facenet model to predict. I load them first.

```
modelPic = load_model('models/pp.h5')
lePic = pickle.loads(open('models/pp.pickle', "rb").read())
print(modelPic.predict(np.zeros((1, 128, 128, 3))))

modelM = load_model('models/pv.h5')
leM = pickle.loads(open('models/pv.pickle', "rb").read())
print(modelM.predict(np.zeros((1, 128, 128, 3))))
```

I print the fake image to test the models. It seems to work normally. But when I run flask server and try to post an image to this api, the message pop up and the prediction doesn't work.

```
Tensor input_1_3:0, specified in either feed_devices or fetch_devices was not found in the Graph
Exception ignored in: <bound method BaseSession._Callable.__del__ of <tensorflow.python.client.session.BaseSession._Callable object at 0x7ff27d0f0dd8>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/idgate/.virtualenvs/Line_POC/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1455, in __del__
    self._session._session, self._handle, status)
  File "/home/idgate/.virtualenvs/Line_POC/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 528, in __exit__
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: No such callable handle: 140675571821088
```

I try to use these two keras model without loading facenet model in flask server. It works normally. I think that it must collide with something (maybe about session?) to make these three models cannot work simultaneously. But I don't know how to solve this problem. Please help me! Thanks in advance.